# Taking a list of numbers from text file, turning to single string, then splitting that list by spaces or comma into two array lists

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, int

so the title it kinda wordy so I will try to explain my question better.

So basically what this program is going to do is, take a big list of numbers imported from a text file (which is sorted like this):

```
3679       87
196        60
17914      12
18618      64
2370       65
... ...
etc. (for 45 more lines),
```

then sort the two columns into two different array's, and then sort them by integer value. The left column is the item ID, while the right column is the number of units in stock.

What I have tried so far: I tried to make the entire list into a single string array and then I tried to split the array into two array lists, and separate them by every comma. But I couldn't successfully do that. Also, I tried to do it in a for loop where it skips ever comma and just adds the next value into the two different arraylists.

Here is my current code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Store {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // **************Scanner s = new
    // Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> inventory = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> numbersString = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        int x = 0;
        int s = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("file50.txt"));
        in.useDelimiter(",");

        while (in.hasNext()) {// grabs all numbers in text file
            String f = in.next();
            numbersString.add(f);
            String toPrint = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < numbersString.size(); i++) {
                toPrint += numbersString.get(i) + " ";
            }

            String[] nums = toPrint.split("\\s+");
            // System.out.println(toPrint);
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(nums));
            // System.out.print(nums);
        }

    } catch (Exception i) {

        i.printStackTrace();
    }

}
   }
```

If anyone could help me out and suggest what I should do to achieve my goal, it would be greatly appreciated. And if I still didn't make it clear enough on what i'm trying to do, let me know. I'll try to explain it the best I can

I don't want copy and paste code, just an idea of what to do.

Thanks

Comment: From the looks of it, your for loop needs to be outside the while loop. Your toPrint String is going to contain many duplicates as every time you're going through the elements in the list. Also why are you using a comma delimiter? I don't see any commas in your text file?

Comment: @AliAlamiri Well, this was just a test I had used in past attempts of doing it. It doesn't seem to be doing anything. Also, when I moved the for loop out of the while loop, it didn't seem to make a difference :/

Comment: See the answer I provided, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if the values in your text file are separated by spaces, then get rid of the `in.useDelimiter(",");`.

Second thing when reading a line from your file, use `String f = in.nextLine();` instead of `String f = in.next();`

So now you are going to read each line from the file, with ID and stock items separated by a space.

Now if you want to get the ID and stock item separately, you can do this:

```
String[] tokens = f.split(" "); //splits the input by spaces
```

So now you have the ID at `tokens[0]` and the stock items at `tokens[1];`

So every time you read a line, split it by a space, then you can add the ID to the List of IDs using `tokens[0]` and the inventory to the List of inventories using `tokens[1]`

On another note, I recommend using a `Map` where the IDs are the keys and the stock items are the value, instead of using multiple Lists.

So something like:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put(tokens[0],tokens[1]);
```

If instead of `String` you want the IDs and stock items to be integers, you can do something like:

```
int ID = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
```